# Alpha Vantage error when symbol has digits

Tags: alpha-vantage

I'm trying to get quotes for an Australian stock with ticker A200.AX (*aka* A200.AUS) from Alpha Vantage.

I have no issues getting other symbols from the AX market, e.g.:
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=ETHI.AUS&apikey=demo
...returns data as expected

However when a symbol has **digit(s)** in it, it seems to return an error:
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=A200.AUS&apikey=demo
`Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY.`
Same result for `F100.AUS`

I checked to make sure the ticker was valid: A200.AUS shows up if I search for it:
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=A200.AUS&apikey=demo

I'm aware of some questions related to URL encoding, but I can't see any URL special characters in `A200.AUS`  . Besides, using the search endpoint works with the ticker passed on literally.
Does anyone know how to download this stock's information or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of the search endpoint is great, however A200.AUS is an ETF. Alpha Vantage has some ETFs, but currently, only 100% supports stocks.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, that's true: the API's documentation makes it clear that it's for "stocks".  
The thing that still confuses me is that my working example (with ETHI.AUS) ... is also an ETF.
In fact I can pull all the ETFs in my portfolio from AlphaVantage (NDQ.AUS, VAP.AUS, ETHI.AUS) ... with the exception of those with digits in the symbol. Which is why I thought it had something to do with numbers.

Comment: At the moment, any additional ETFs that are supported are considered a bonus, but it's not currently. However, that should change in the future.

Comment: Okay, the digit thing must have been a coincidence: I managed to download data from a regular stock with digits in in (A2M, a milk company stock)